# Popup onclick Javascript doesn't work

Tags: javascript, popup, popupwindow

I am building a form which will be loaded in popup by clicking on a text/image. This is my code and it is not working! Any ideas

```
<div>
<a href="?remind_me" id="remindmelink" onclick="">Remind me</a>
</div>

<div class="map-popup" id="remindme" style="display:none;">
<form>
    <label for="remind_me_email" class="required"><em>*</em>E-Mail Address</label>
    <div class="input-box">
        <input type="text" id="remind_me_email" title="E-Mail Address" />
    </div>
</form>
<div>
    <button type="submit" class="button" id="remind_me_submit"><span>Submit</span>       </button>
</div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery('#remindmelink').click(function(){
e.preventDefault();
jQuery('#remindme').dialog('open');
return false;
});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was jQuery conflict as some javascript was copied inline in some other pages! Solved by removing the inline scripts and using

```
var j = jQuery.noConlifct();
j(document).ready(function(){
j('#remindmelink').click(function(){
j('#remindme').fancybox();
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//open popup
var myPoplink = document.getElementById('remindmelink');
$(myPoplink).on('click',function(){
alert('Hello!'); // to be replaced with $('#remindme').dialog('open');
});
});
```

Comment: same thing! Page refresh but no alert!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$(document).on('click','#remindmelink',function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   alert('Hello!'); // to be replaced with $('#remindme').dialog('open');
});
```

**UPDATE**:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery('#remindmelink').click(function(){
    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery('#remindme').show();
    jQuery('#remindme').dialog('open');
    return false;
  });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/LbDXJ/)

Comment: tried it before my last version of the code and not working! Page refresh no alert!

Comment: Fiddle is working. Page refresh no alert??? alert is on click, are you clicking link :)

Comment: It was a conflict in jQuery! Now Alert appears but pop doesn't work! Look at the code I updated!

Comment: same this @aleesandro! The idea is don't want to show the div anyway! I hate to maintain code after someone :D

Answer (score 0):

invalid `$('.myPoplink')` selector. i.e there is no class `.myPoplink` found in the HTML. Try using `$('#remindmelink')`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  //open popup  
  $("#remindmelink").on('click',function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      alert('Hello!'); // to be replaced with $('#remindme').dialog('open');

  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case put `href="#"` here is the
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TZGKY/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //open popup

      $(document).on('click','#remindmelink',function(){
       alert('Hello!'); // to be replaced with $('#remindme').dialog('open');
       return false;
      });

    });
```